# Как назначить открываемые файлы в QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы открывались только два определенных файла(их директории я знаю).
Попробовал сделать так(это слот, вызывается по нажатию кнопки):

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Open File", "", "*.txt");
file = new QFile(filename);
if (filename!="C:/Users/Личный/Desktop/dates.txt/" || filename!="C:/Users/Личный/Desktop/pustoi.txt/")
//Выскакивает диалоговое окно
```

Чтобы условием проверялась директория. Но это не сработало. Есть какой-то другой способ, или может мой как-то исправить?

Comment: Если вам надо открыть один из двух файлов, сделайте кастомный диалог, в котором пользователь в выпадающем списке выберет нужный файл. Не надо давать пользователю иллюзию выбора, а потом бить по рукам за неправильный выбор

Comment: такое задание, ничего не поделаешь)

Comment: Ну тада какое задание, такое и решение - `if (filename != "C:\\Users\\Личный\\Desktop\\dates.txt"` должно прокатить. И у вас условие кривое, вам надо `&&`. Сейчас условие всегда истинно.